# htaccess, ressources not found and links redirected to localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, hyperlink

I would like to upload my website to a server test

so I uploaded all to a test server

there http://changeyourbody.fr/spb/

the trouble I have is that all images, js file, and others, are not found

and they are all uploaded to the ftp, so they should be found

moreover all links brings to localhost

this is what I do not understand

I just set up a url rewrite

in the ht access like that

```
php_flag output_buffering on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php/p/([^/.]+)(\.html)?$ ?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

and my links are liek that

```
<a href="index.php/p/accueil">Accueil</a>
```

I do not know what's wrong did I have done ?

anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: What are examples of some links for css/ja that are not found (open your page in Firebug for that).

Comment: the trouble is not on the main page, but on other pages http://changeyourbody.fr/spb/index.php/p/chantier&id=11 for example and there all images are not found because, it takes the current url as main folder, so it looks for images like that http://changeyourbody.fr/spb/index.php/p/images/....jpg but in fact there all from the main folder

Comment: the page not found, probably it's all about that redirect, give us a real path of those files to we can check the Rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You've hit the most common problem people face when switching to pretty URL schemes. Solution is simple, just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Option 2:**

You can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`